# Writing a value to another worksheet "Subscript out of range" error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm absolutely new to VBA and in need to write some simple VBA code to make some calculations.
I have a Userform called fKitsel that makes user to choose one of 6 options and writes the number of chosen option as `Public Kit As Integer` variable to the worksheet Лист2(Variables) (I need to use an Ukrainian excel localization in my organization).
The write occurs when the User pushes cbsubmit command button.
Sub for this looks like:

```
Sub cbsubmit_Click()       
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Лист2").Range("A1").Value = Kit ' error points here
    Лист2.Activate
    Unload Me    
End Sub
```

And when I click the cbsubmit button I receive an "Subscript out of range" error which points to the line I commented in the code block.
Cant get what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I don't think VBA likes having non-english character in the Editor so instead of referring `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Лист2").Range("A1").Value`, use its `CodeName` instead e.g. `Sheet1.Range("A1").Value` (In VBA editor's Project Pane, it's the name on the left side of the worksheet object, the one in bracket is the worksheet name).

Comment: Thank you for the tip. The problem is that the CodeNames themselves are using Cyrillic characters, example: Лист1(MainList). If I get it right, the CodeName is 'Лист1' and it's worksheet name (which I've given him using Rename in Excel itself) is 'MainList'.
So now I'm trying next thing: 'Лист2.Range("A1").Value = Kit' and now I get a Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: So the name you see inside Excel under the worksheet tab is `MainList`? In this case you can try `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MainList").Range("A1").Value`. (I'm assuming the workbook where you run the code is the same workbook where `MainList` is in. It's not a good idea to use `ActiveWorkbook` as the reference changes the moment you change your focus to another workbook which might not be your intention) @Stas

Comment: @RaymondWu Thanks. Referred the way you suggested. Still error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error that refers to the reference row.

Comment: What do you mean by `refers to the reference row`? Is the error still on the same line? If not then you need to show more code. @Stas

Comment: @RaymondWu Still refers to this same row.
Here is a link to this file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Tnz49VgmGUQnwfEPf97J8x9nZhr567YO/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The document requires access permission, can you remove it? @Stas

Comment: @RaymondWu Sorry. Removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Userform contains a `Frame` control named `Kit`, the same name as the `Kit` variable in `Module1` module, this causes the confusion in this line:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("VarList").Range("A1").Value = Kit
```

As it also means:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("VarList").Range("A1").Value = Me.Kit `(which is the frame control)
```

You can either give different and distinct name to each control/variables (which is a better way, give more descriptive name to your variable/control e.g. `frameKit`)

Or be explicit in what variable are you referring to, like:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("VarList").Range("A1").Value = Module1.Kit
```

Comment: Yes, the problem was in the ambiguous naming of  different items in this book. Thank you, will always keep track on how I'm naming things even if they are totally different =)
Your help saved this day.

Comment: As any of the answers submitted to your question resolved your issue, you may accept it by clicking the tick beside the answer (you can only accept one if there are multiple answers) so you can accept either mine or Matt's answer, depending which answers is best to your need @Stas